# Git live preview HTML file does not working

Tags: html, github

I am working on the odin project and make my first html project, the first recipe project.
I have now finished it and upload it to my repo on github. If I want to see it with live preview the index.html page is working well. But if I click on a link at the index page it does not working.
Can u check my html file?
Or is it maybe that I have make failure with github workflow. I have changed/finished my coding on MS VisualStudio and then add the following statements in the terminal:

```
git add .
git commit -m "something"
git push origin main
```

My Repo:
https://github.com/ztrk-dev/odin-recipes/tree/main/recipes

Comment: GitHub isn't a hosting provider (except through GitHub Pages), so clicking links on HTML pages is unlikely to do anything interesting, since that requires there to be a host, a web server set up to serve the HTML according to the rules of HTTP. The Live Preview  provides a way of previewing a single HTML file in isolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hosting what Github Pages refers to as a [Project site](https://pages.github.com/), which means the page is being hosted at "*username*.github.io/*repository*".

The reason the pages with images aren't loading as expected(if I'm misunderstanding the question let me know) is because they are linked as `/images/spaghetti-napoli.jpeg`, which is a relative file path for the file spaghetti-napoli.jpeg that is located in a folder "images" located in the root directory. The problem is that the root directory `/` isn't the base directory of your project site. `/{repo-name}/` is (so that you could have many different projects with their own websites if you wanted to).

If you want the repository to be the root of your site, you'd need a [User site](https://pages.github.com/), which would require a repository named `ztrk-dev.github.io` to host the projects files. If you'd rather use a project site, you would need to link the images as `/{repo-name}/{path-to-file}` instead of `/{path-to-file}`.

That is to say, `/images/spaghetti-napoli.jpeg` would become
`/odin-recipes/images/spaghetti-napoli.jpeg` or `../images/spaghetti-napoli.jpeg`

Comment: Hey thx, I have now edited my index.html and it works now. I have onla delete the first /